# Replace String with Text

Tags: php, html

I have a website made by previous developed( Now he is not available ).
I have to access to CMS, payment backend everything, But old developer didnt left any records of database. 
I am trying to rename or replace some of the text(company details) in receipt, but I dont know what am i doing wrong. 
If I had an access to DB , it would be ease like butter. 
Here is what I want to do :
[image: Picture] 
You can see that I tried to include direct text "www.transit.com" , but it didnt show up on receipt . 
Instead it showed blank.
I know its pointing to DB name like 'shop_name' and so on. But since I dont have any details on DB , I cant change it from DB.

```js
    function setShopData() {
        // ショップ情報

        $objDb = new SC_Helper_DB_Ex();
        $arrInfo = $objDb->sfGetBasisData();

        // ショップ名
        $this->lfText(125, 60, $arrInfo['shop_name'], 8, 'B');
        // URL
        $this->lfText(125, 63, $arrInfo['www.transit.com'], 8);
        // 会社名
        $this->lfText(125, 68, $arrInfo['law_company'], 8);
        // 郵便番号
        $text = '〒 ' . $arrInfo['law_zip01'] . ' - ' . $arrInfo['law_zip02'];
        $this->lfText(125, 71, $text, 8);
        // 都道府県+所在地
        $text = $this->arrPref[$arrInfo['law_pref']] . $arrInfo['law_addr01'];
        $this->lfText(125, 74, $text, 8);
        $this->lfText(125, 77, $arrInfo['law_addr02'], 8);

        $text = 'TEL: '.$arrInfo['law_tel01'].'-'.$arrInfo['law_tel02'].'-'.$arrInfo['law_tel03'];
        //FAX番号が存在する場合、表示する
        if (strlen($arrInfo['law_fax01']) > 0) {
            $text .= '　FAX: '.$arrInfo['law_fax01'].'-'.$arrInfo['law_fax02'].'-'.$arrInfo['law_fax03'];
        }
        $this->lfText(125, 80, $text, 8);  //TEL・FAX

        if (strlen($arrInfo['media-support.transit-grp.com']) > 0) {
            $text = 'Email: '.'media-support.transit-grp.com';
            $this->lfText(125, 83, $text, 8);      //Email
        }
```

So is there anyway I can replace these code, so that it would reflect on receipt? 
Thank you

Comment: Can you please share your code, not a screenshot.

Comment: I have edited a post, and added the code. @Anas

Comment: Try $this->lfText(125, 63, 'www.transit.com', 8);

Comment: You will need to look at the $objDB->sfGetBasisData() function to see where the information is coming from. Alternatively just use the a string for the data i.e. $this->lfText(125,60,'my company',8,'B');

Comment: @ChrisCousins You are a life saver. How Do i mark your reply or comment as answer ?

Comment: @jeff Yes its coming from DB, unfortunately I dont have DB login or password, But Chrish comments is same as yours and its solved.

Comment: there you go, posted as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$this->lfText(125, 63, 'www.transit.com', 8);
```

You were referring to your array, but it didn't contain that key, you simply wanted to use a hardcoded string instead.

For the email (for instance) do:

```
$text = 'Email: mycompany@gmail.com';
$this->lfText(125, 83, $text, 8);
```

Comment: Thank you. But having an issue with Email. I did the same way, but it gives me error.

Comment: Please edit your code in the question to show how you are handling the email.

Comment: It's a rabbit hole! Don't follow Chris. Just my advise

Comment: I have edited the answer to show how to put email hardcoded in.

Comment: @Andreas yes, realizing that now haha!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the best option is to replace the value in the array, that way any other places where this name is used will also be replaced.

```
function setShopData() {
    // ショップ情報

    // Here is the change:
    $arrInfo['shop_name'] = "something else";

    $objDb = new SC_Helper_DB_Ex();
    $arrInfo = $objDb->sfGetBasisData();

    // ショップ名
    $this->lfText(125, 60, $arrInfo['shop_name'], 8, 'B');
    // URL
    $this->lfText(125, 63, $arrInfo['www.transit.com'], 8);
    // 会社名
    $this->lfText(125, 68, $arrInfo['law_company'], 8);
    // 郵便番号
    $text = '〒 ' . $arrInfo['law_zip01'] . ' - ' . $arrInfo['law_zip02'];
    $this->lfText(125, 71, $text, 8);
    // 都道府県+所在地
    $text = $this->arrPref[$arrInfo['law_pref']] . $arrInfo['law_addr01'];
    $this->lfText(125, 74, $text, 8);
    $this->lfText(125, 77, $arrInfo['law_addr02'], 8);

    $text = 'TEL: '.$arrInfo['law_tel01'].'-'.$arrInfo['law_tel02'].'-'.$arrInfo['law_tel03'];
    //FAX番号が存在する場合、表示する
    if (strlen($arrInfo['law_fax01']) > 0) {
        $text .= '　FAX: '.$arrInfo['law_fax01'].'-'.$arrInfo['law_fax02'].'-'.$arrInfo['law_fax03'];
    }
    $this->lfText(125, 80, $text, 8);  //TEL・FAX

    if (strlen($arrInfo['law_email']) > 0) {
        $text = 'Email: '.$arrInfo['law_email'];
        $this->lfText(125, 83, $text, 8);      //Email
    }
```

One thing that I find odd is `function setShopData() {` that is usually `function setShopData($arrInfo) {`.
Since that is missing I assume the array is global and is set somewhere else.
At some point in the code there is a line like:

```
$arrInfo['shop_name'] =<database value>
```

If you place the line above in the code just below this any changes in the rest of the code will have the new shopname everywhere, not just on the receipt.

Comment: There is no error if you set an array value. And how am I supposed to know what the error is if you don't tell me!

Comment: I added the $arrInfo['law_email''] = "xxxx@xxx.com . Once i execute this, page throws me Error. with its default setting, it is giving me older email value, But after inserting this code, whole page is blank after execution